# Environment variable does not work with docker windows Image

Tags: windows, docker, cmd, dockerfile

I have the next dockerfile, with build image in two stage

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR worker-app

ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

#BUILD PROJECT
RUN mkdir c:\worker-app\out
...

#BUILD IMAGE
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8
WORKDIR /worker-app

COPY --from=build /worker-app/out .

#Install AWS CLI
RUN echo Descargando aws-cli
RUN curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64PY3.msi -o AWSCLI64PY3.msi
RUN echo Instalando aws-cli
RUN msiexec /i AWSCLI64PY3.msi /qn /norestart
RUN setx Path "%Path%;\"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\""

#Login AWS CLI

CMD ["cmd", "/S", "/C", "aws configure set aws_access_key_id "%AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID%" && aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "%AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY%" && aws configure set default.region us-east-1 && aws configure set default.output json"]

ENTRYPOINT ["cmd"]
```

the build command works fine

```
 docker build -t worker-app:1 .
```

but my issue is when I try to run the image like that

```
docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=123456789 -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="abcde123456" -it --entrypoint=cmd worker-app:1
```

and I type `aws configure` but all keys are empty, also, I try to do `echo %AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID% && ...` in the line CMD but never print it.

Any idea?

Comment: This is a very important warning about part of your code. Do not corrupt your environment by using `setx.exe` with `Path`. `Path` is a special Environment variable which is a concatenation of the System variable `Path` data, and the User variable `Path` data. What you're effectively doing is permanently adding everything from your System `Path` plus `"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\"` to your User `Path`. You have now got multiple duplicates in your User `Path` which require removal. Also your new location should not be doublequoted, and there's no need for a trailing backward slash.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected CMD command:

```
CMD ["cmd", "/S", "/C", "aws configure set aws_access_key_id $env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID && aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY && aws configure set default.region us-east-1 && aws configure set default.output json"]
```

Also, it is worth noting that you are using cmd as the entrypoint, so the CMD command will always run in a new instance of the cmd shell and the environment variables won't persist between runs. To persist the environment variables, you can add the following line to the Dockerfile:

```
ENV PATH="%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin"
```